# Redirect to other URL if no string present [JAVASCRIPT]

Tags: javascript, string, types, indexing, undefined

In my php page there is error of "Undefined Index type". But if the same URL is opened with string e.g. mypage.php?type=abc then this error is not shown!

I want to redirect users without string i.e. from mypage.php to mypage.php?type=abc

I decided better to correct php!
Php code follows

```
<?
if (($_REQUEST["type"] == "mz") || ($_REQUEST["type"] == "ie") || ($_REQUEST["type"] == "iea")) {
?>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="icons/<?= $_REQUEST['id'] ?>_favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<?
}
?>

<?
if ($_REQUEST["type"] == "mza") {
?>
    <link rel="icon" href="icons/<?= $_REQUEST['id'] ?>_extra_animated_favicon.gif" type="image/x-icon">
<? } ?>
```

There is error in 2 line and last line

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just output the default content by PHP instead of redirecting the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function urlRD(){
if (location.href == "http://mypage.php")
window.location = "http://mypage.php?type=abc"
}

</script>
```

And then:

```
<body onLoad="urlRD()">
```

Comment: But when parameters more than 1 ?

Comment: Its good! But bodyonload function wanna be not better and as said by Boris Gappov, i can accept your answer because Boris Gappov has a good answer! But really appreciate for your work! Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want to do this:

```
window.location.href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?type=abc';
```

Even better, fix your PHP code so that you don't get any warnings on notices!

Comment: But where do you check if type parameter exists?

Answer (score 0):

Either you correct the problem in the PHP file or add an .htaccess entry to redirect the user directly.

I suggest adding some code to the PHP file like so:

```
if (!isset($_GET)) { //or you can use more specifically if (!isset($_GET['type'])) { 

//there is no get variables here so we either add a local variable or redirect (which is redundant)

$type = "abc"; //or even $_GET['type'] = "abc";

//redirect header("location: mypage.php?type=abc");

}else{

//execute work

}
```

to alter the .htaccess requires certain previledges some people don't have.

EDIT: a javascript way of doing this is also possible but also the *laggiest* and less recommendable.

**IN RESPONSE TO YOUR UPDATE:**

You probably need to check for $_REQUEST['id'] before using it; (you may do it the same way I presented above)

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {

//do your code

}
else {

//no ID here

}
```

ALSO it may be that you server doesn't support short tags (`<?= ?>`), try to use echo instead:

```
echo "<link blah blah blah=\"$_REQUEST[id]_icon.ico\" blah />";
```

Comment: I think it was not there at the time I answered the question. Anyway even so This IS the best solution!

Comment: Update my answered in a very relevant way, regarding your question update.